# jsPDF "Object expected" Exception in IE when trying to save the PDF

Tags: jspdf

When trying to save the PDF file, the following stack trace occurs and the file is not downloaded:

```
TypeError: Object expected
at API.save (http://localhost:8080/applications/lib/jspdf/jspdf.debug.js:3648:11)
at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8080/applications/js/<my_custom_js_file>.js:288:12)
at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8080/applications/lib/angular-1.5.8/angular.min.js:158:482)
at e (http://localhost:8080/applications/lib/angular-1.5.8/angular.min.js:45:442)
at Anonymous function (http://localhost:8080/applications/lib/angular-1.5.8/angular.min.js:48:300)
```

Also tried with a simple example and had the same results:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text("hello", 20, 20);
doc.save("table.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not support native Promise. Therefore, the initialization script fails at line 12016 of Version 1.5.3:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' is undefined
jspdf.debug.js (12016,5)
```

Afterwards, the script is no longer initializing the required context.

A fix should be a 3rd party promise library - I have solved it by including the following resources before including jspdf.debug.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/applications/lib/ie-promise/es6-promise.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/applications/lib/ie-promise/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>
```